# FastAPI and Pydantic AnyOf in an Array

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

Is there a way to declare an AnyOf in Pydantic with FastAPI like this?

```py
class RedPill(BaseModel):
    kind: str = Literal['red']
    name: str
    size: int


class BluePill(BaseModel):
    kind: str = Literal['blue']
    serialnumber: str


class Matrix(BaseModel):
    year: int
    pills: List[Union[RedPill, BluePill]] = []


@api.post('/')
def sample(data: Matrix):
    return
```

How do I represent a valid array of different objects.

Comment: you mean that `Matrix` is a list of `Union[RedPill, BluePill]`?

Comment: In Json this would be {"year": 2021, "pills": [ {"kind": "blue", "serialnumber": "123"}, {"kind": "red", "name": "foo", "size": 100} ] }

Answer (score 2):

You were really close: You just need to change the Literal into the type and it should work.

You can read about literal [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#literal-type).

```py
from pprint import pprint
from typing import List, Union
    
from pydantic.main import BaseModel
from pydantic.typing import Literal
    
    
class RedPill(BaseModel):
    kind: Literal['red']
    name: str
    size: int
    
    
class BluePill(BaseModel):
    kind: Literal['blue']
    serialnumber: str
    
    
class Matrix(BaseModel):
    year: int
    pills: List[Union[RedPill, BluePill]] = []
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pprint(Matrix.parse_obj({"year": 2021, "pills": [ {"kind": "blue", "serialnumber": "123"}, {"kind": "red", "name": "foo", "size": 100} ] }).dict())
## {'pills': [{'kind': 'blue', 'serialnumber': '123'},
           {'kind': 'red', 'name': 'foo', 'size': 100}],
 'year': 2021}
```